# Детский вопрос: прилагательные от слова «колобок»

Tags: лексика, словообразование, прилагательные, словосочетания

У девочки в школе была "домашняя викторина" (то есть к членам семьи обращаться не возбранялось, даже наоборот). Нужно было *найти* (или придумать) прилагательные от слова "колобок" и составить с ними словосочетания.
**Мы** нашли и составили:
***колобкастая** собака* (толстая, круглая);
***колобковое** тесто* (для изготовления, выпечки колобков);
***колобокская** сказка* (сказка о колобке).

Девочка получила очень хорошую оценку.
Но было сказано, что словосочетания не совсем правильные и что есть ещё ***другие*** прилагательные.

Скажите: *что* неправильно в словосочетаниях и какие *ещё* можно использовать прилагательные?

Comment: К слову колобок? Круглый колобок.  "Колобкастый" - это прилагательное образованное от слова "колобок".

Comment: Спасибо. *Мы* поторопились. Исправились.

Comment: Колобочный, колобкиный, колобчатый, колобоческий... :))

Comment: аст субстансивный суффикс - производный от ат ("имеющий частью"), только в функциональном смысле. Колобкастая могло бы значить - собака, которая катается как колобок. https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/otsubstantivnye-suffiksalnye-prilagatelnye-s-semantikoy-intensivnosti-v-russkom-yazyke-sistemno-funktsionalnyy-podhod/viewer

Answer (score 3):

Даль говорит, что колобок от колоб, а прилагательное будет [колобенчатый](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/256578).

> Колобенчатый пск., твер. о скоте, выкормленный и холеный, взросший на колобах.

**Колобенчатая собака** или **колобака**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тесто для печенья - песочное, тесто для блинов - блинное, венское тесто - какой-то новодел, в энциклопедии Брокгауза и Ефрона "венское тесто" - это разъедающее вещество...

Тесто для колобков - сдобное, тесто вряд ли называется по тому, для чего оно. Ну или **кóлобовое тесто**? [Колобовый пирог](https://www.novochag.ru/recipes/znamenityy-russkiy-kolobovyy-pirog/)

СК - суффикс принадлежности какому-то лицу или к месту. Например, Фиванский цикл - цикл мифов связанный с городом Фивы, но Фив как героя там нет.

Сказки про колобка - русские-народные или литературные.
Арлекиниада - это вроде пьеса или жанр, про героя(кстати, арлекин - harlequin это Харли Квинн); хотя, Энеида, Илиада - но всё таки это стихи или пьесы, а у нас сказка, так что Колобкиада вряд ли подойдет.
Еще, можно попробовать, Одиссея, Орестея~Колобея или Колобчея.
И это не прилагательные...

Еще есть латинский суффикс [-ана-](https://www.novochag.ru/recipes/znamenityy-russkiy-kolobovyy-pirog/) связанный как с историями о.. так и прочими мерчами и тп. - Поттериана, например. Колобчиана - но опять же, не прилагательное и суффикс латинский.

Хотя, есть казачьи сказки еще - может **колобочьи сказки**?

Еще на ум приходят, если колобок - это земной шар, то космогонические мифы - **колобкогонические сказки**?

Comment: Здорово — ну и фантазия у Вас!.. Собачку жалко... А пирог, наверно, *колобовый*?

Comment: собачку добавил, пирог поправил, спасибо за замечание - на одно смотрю, другого не вижу, такая проблемка)

Comment: Ну... Прямо колобок на ножках или с ножками. Не идет — катится. Думаю, что о такой собаке все-таки можно сказать *колобкастая* (так мы с ребенком и рассуждали). Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Правильно ещё писать так: *Колобóчное тесто.*

Comment: А что Вы скажете о правильности или неправильности наших словосочетаний?

Comment: Оно тоже 100-процентно правильны-с.